# zsh read input in zle widget

Tags: zsh, readline

I am trying to implement a custom version of zsh history search when pressing `ctrl-r` (although my function will map to different shortcut).

So far I have tried to use `read` , `vared` and `read-command` to read input after user presses the bespoke shortcut. My code looks like:

```
# Bind \eg to `git status`
function _cust-hist {
    zle -I
    local line
    read -r line
    echo $line
    zle accept-line
}
zle -N _cust-hist
bindkey '\eg' _cust-hist
```

But nothing seems to work. I must be missing something obvious, is this possible with zsh?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's definitely possible.

This should get you started:

```
function _cust-hist {
  local REPLY
  autoload -Uz read-from-minibuffer

  # Create a sub-prompt, pre-populated with the current contents of the command line.
  read-from-minibuffer 'History search: ' $LBUFFER $RBUFFER

  # Use the modified input to search history & update the command line with it.
  LBUFFER=$(echo "$(fc -ln $REPLY $REPLY)" )
  RBUFFER=''

  # Put some informational text below the command line.
  zle -M "History result for '$REPLY'."
}
zle -N _cust-hist
bindkey '\eg' _cust-hist
```

If you're interested in how `read-from-minibuffer` works, you can find its [source code over here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Zle/read-from-minibuffer). As you can see, it uses `read -k` or `zle recursive-edit` to get input from the user.